# Positioning background image fixed bottom center

Tags: css

http://www.bunzburgerz.com/

If you look at the background image I'm not able to get it to position to the bottom of the page.  Despite having `height: 100%`, the body tag doesn't want to make it work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `height: 100%;` to html tag as well as to body tag